# Proving that a group where every subgroup has a finite number of conjugates has the following property:

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group in which each subgroup has a finite number of conjugates in G. Let H $\leq$ G and $x \in G$. Prove that $H \cap xHx^{-1}$ is a subgroup of finite index in H.

Answer (score 1):

The conjugates of any subgroup of a group are in one-to-one correspondence with cosets of its normalizer and so, because $\langle x \rangle$ has (by hypothesis) only finitely many conjugates in $G$, $|G:N_G(\langle x \rangle)| < \infty$. Moreover, the centralizer $C_G(x)$ is the kernel of the conjugation action of $N_G(\langle x \rangle)$ on $\langle x \rangle$ and so the quotient $N_G(\langle x \rangle)/C_G(x)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the automorphism group of $\langle x \rangle$. But the automorphism group of any cyclic group is finite and so $|G:C_G(x)| < \infty$. But $|G:C_G(x)|$ is the number of $G$-conjugates of $x$, whence the number of $H$-conjugates of $x$, $|H:H \cap C_G(x)|$, is also finite.

Since $H \cap C_G(x) = x(H \cap C_G(x))x^{-1} \le H \cap xHx^{-1}$, it follows that $|H:H \cap xHx^{-1}|  \le |H:H \cap C_G(x)| < \infty$.