# $H \cap x^{-1} H x$ has finite index in $H$ for every $x \in G$ if $H$ has a finite number of conjugates in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group in which each subgroup has a finite number of conjugates in $G$. Then, for each subgroup $H$ of $G$, $H \cap x^{-1} H x$ is a subgroup of finite index in $H$ for each $x \in G$.

This is an exercise from the book Problems in Group Theory by J. Dixon. I can't understand his proposed solution at the end of the book. He starts by considering the subgroup $\langle x \rangle$. Given that $\langle x \rangle$ has a finite number of conjugates in $G$, then $[G: N(\langle x \rangle; G)] < \infty$ (note: here $N(\langle x \rangle; G)$ is the normalizer of $\langle x \rangle$ in $G$). After restricting to $H$, we can say that $[H: N(\langle x \rangle;H)]$ is also finite. Now, he says the following: $N(\langle x \rangle; H) \subseteq H \cap x^{-1} H x$ and, because of that, $[H: H \cap x^{-1} H x]$ is finite.

I can't see how $N(\langle x \rangle; H) \subseteq H \cap x^{-1} H x$. If I have some $h \in N(\langle x \rangle; H)$, then $h \in H$ immediately. However, how does the condition $h^{-1} \langle x \rangle h = \langle x \rangle$ guarantees the existence of some $h_0 \in H$ such that $x^{-1} h_0 x = h$?

Comment: Just to clarify, is $N(\langle x\rangle; H)$ the intersection of the normalizer with $H$?

Comment: @redwhisker $N(\langle x \rangle; H) = \{h \in H ; h^{-1} \langle x \rangle h = \langle x \rangle\}$. So, yes, I think it is the intersection.

Comment: I have deleted my answer, I misread it as finite index. In any case, counter example: $G = S_3, H = \{(), (12)\}, x = (123)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096964/proving-that-a-group-where-every-subgroup-has-a-finite-number-of-conjugates-has?rq=1